My SCSS does not work beyond a certain point on my live server
The SCSS code only works up to right before the default styles comment.
My SCSS compiles with no errors, I linked the file properly, in fact I used !important to see if it was overwritten and that didn't work either. My code editor is vs code.
Here is the html and the scss:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fahdriss Farms</title>
    <!-- Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">

        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>SHOP</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
            <li>CONTACT US</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-buttons">

        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main code -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main-container">
            <!--Hero-->
            <div class="hero">
                <div class="hero-container">
                    <div class="hero-right">
                        <img src="./img/dawadawa.png" alt="Spice picture" class="bg-spice">
                    </div>

                    <div class="hero-left">
                        <h1>SUN BOWL</h1>
                        <p>Feel more then can...</p>

                        <!-- Catalog -->

                        <a href="./catalog.html">
                            <button>
                                Look ->
                            </button>
                        </a>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    //overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

// mixins
@mixin divCentered {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

// default styles
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    .logo {

    }
    ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        
    }
    .main {
        
        .main-container {
            border-radius: 2px solid red !important;
            
            .hero {
                .hero-container {
                    
                    .hero-right {
                        img {
                            
                        }
                    }

                    .hero-left {
                        h1 {

                        }
                        p {

                        }
                        button {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Media Queries

// mobile screens
@media (width >= 320px) {
    nav {
        .main {
            .main-container {
                border: 2px solid red;
                .hero {
                    
                    .hero-container {
                        border: 1px solid black;
                        padding: 2rem;
                        .hero-right {
                            border: 2px solid black;
                            .bg-spice {
                                
                            }
                        }
    
                        .hero-left {
                            h1 {
    
                            }
                            p {

                            }
                            button {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Tablets 
@media (width >= 768px) {
    .hero-container {
        
    }
}

// Laptops 
@media (width >= 1024px) {

}

// Large laptops
@media (width >= 1440px) {

}

It also doesn't work in the media query curly braces.

The file is linked as CSS in the HTML. You need to compile the SCSS file into CSS before you can use it.

//  is not the way to comment CSS. Use /* etc */.

The next problem is that .main is nested inside nav in the SCSS but they're not nested in the HTML so any .main style rules won't be applied.

Guy Incognito I already did compile it.

@Paulie_D The code is intended as SCSS, a server-side language which extends CSS and compiles back to it. It uses // for comments which should not be output to the browser.

What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? What are you seeing, and what are you expecting to see? Try to come up with a [mre] - you can start by removing all the sections of your SCSS which don't actually have any rules in them.

There is no .main and .main-container under nav.

Well, the issue with your SCSS code seems to stem from incorrect syntax in the media queries, I suppose.
Specifically, the media query condition should be inside parentheses, but you used >= instead of the correct min-width: syntax.
I'd like you to change from @media (width >= 320px) to @media (min-width: 320px).
And you need to change not only this but also the other media queries.
Good luck!

Thanks to all those who commented and helped, the issue was the position of curly braces in my code which Guy Icognito helped with. I can't reply to comments because I'm a new member, I think.
